# elastic-search insert doc, show success but fail

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I encounter a weird thing with elastic-search. I dump some data from mongodb to es by using python.
the logs shows me one doc is successfully inserted:

```
{
    u'_type': u'article', 
    u'created': True, 
    u'_shards': {
        u'successful': 2, 
        u'failed': 0, 
        u'total': 2
    }, 
    u'_version': 1, 
    u'_index': u'test', 
    u'_id': u'2fc82e861f8301a9629064336f4ba75a'
}
```

but when i use es.exists function. the result show nothing found for me :

```
k = es.exists(index='test', doc_type='article', id='2fc82e861f8301a9629064336f4ba75a')
```

Anyone encounter the same problem and can give some advice?
My es version:2.3.5

Comment: Are you using routing? Do you see the document if you run this `curl -XHEAD localhost:9200/test/article/2fc82e861f8301a9629064336f4ba75a` ?

Comment: I use python library. I set the host. It can search other documents. but only this one failed.

Comment: What about the curl I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into situations where the underscores (or lack thereof) cause problems.

Perhaps you need to try searching using `_index` and `_id`?